# How to select all checkbox by button

Tags: jquery

I'd like to select all input checkbox field on jquery event button click but when I click the button nothing happens

JQUERY

```
$('#selAll').on('click', function() {
   $(".cb").attr('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

HTML

```
    <input type="button" value="Select All" class="btn" id="selAll" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="1" class="cb">
    <input type="checkbox" name="b" value="1" class="cb">
```

which is the best/right solution to do this? thanks
[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zUGw6/2/)

Comment: to select every eement use $("*.cb")

Comment: @Paolo Rossi: please be more specific on what exactly you want..

Comment: @roasted because witht the * you select every element

Comment: @demonofnight but this is same behaviour without using it: `$(".cb")` will returns same set of matched elements than `$("*.cb")`

Comment: @roasted, ohh sorry i imagined that to select all elements you needed to use the *

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check a checkbox, you ought to use the [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) method as such:

```
$('.cb').prop('checked', true);
```

**EDIT:**
This is recommended from the jQuery API Documentation. I see tho you want to toggle, which can be done by this:

```
$('.cb').prop('checked', function(i, val) {return !val;});
```

**EDIT2:**
If you want to toggle all checkboxes on/off by one button, you will have to keep some sort of record telling the script wheter to switch on or off. The easiest would be to change the caption of the button, and do the condition that way. But it's your choice. Example:

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
  // Change values
  $('.cb').prop('checked', ($(this).val() == 'Check'));
  // Change caption of this button
  $(this).val( ($(this).val() == 'Check' ? 'Uncheck' : 'Check') );
});
// HTML
<input type="button" id="button" value="Check" />
```

Of course, if you only want a "Check all" button, my very first code example applies.

Comment: The toggling in your edit is actually toggling from checked to unchecked based on the current item's state (if there are checked and unchecked items, after clicking the item you will also get checked and unchecked items).

Comment: Take a look at OP's original code. He's trying to set the checked value, to a boolean, which evaluates if the checkbox is checked or not. By other words, he's toggling the selection. I just put the latter example in, cause of that.

Comment: @Eric I try this solution and it's ok, but if I use toggle function, when I click button the unchecked field become checked and checked become unchecked. Is it possible to resolve this situation? thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
  $('#selAll').on('click', function() {
    $(".cb").attr('checked', "checked");
  });
```

even `.attr()` also works, but as **roasted** suggested in comment section the recommended function is `.prop()`

```
$('.cb').prop('checked', true);
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: @roasted can't understand it is working, can you explain a bit more? you mean to say for future `.cb` class?

Comment: ok, this is correct if OP wants to check all, i was thinking he wants to toggle state. But .prop() is recommended method even it will change nothing in this case

Comment: @roasted thanks, i also reading the `.prop()` so that get to know why it's recommended on this state. If you don't mind then can you please explain?

Comment: @roasted thanks again, now i know why it's recommended :) , http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 0):

I always set the checked attribute "checked" using a string, not sure if it is the best way to do so but it works in my cases.

In order for you to make it work:

change 
`$(".cb").attr('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));`

to

`$("input.cb").attr('checked', "checked");`

That should work!

Answer (score 0):

Use `!` in front of `$(this).is(":checked")`:

```
$('#selAll').on('click', function () {
    $(".cb").attr('checked', !$(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

function selectAll() {

```
$('.selectedId').attr('checked', isChecked('selectall'));
```

}

function isChecked(checkboxId) {

```
var id = '#' + checkboxId;

return $(id).is(":checked");
```

}